# Load a UILabel from Storyboard, cannot change frame in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I develop an app for iOS6. I have dynamic cells initialized in storyboard, which contains some `UILabels` and some `UIImageViews`. The heights for them may change on the fly. My question is when I change the frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
contentText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:TAG_TOPIC_CONTENT_TEXT];

CGFloat height = [[self.contentHeights objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] floatValue];

contentText.frame = CGRectMake(CELL_TOPIC_CONTENT_X, CELL_TOPIC_CONTENT_Y, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, height);
```

The height of the contentText `UILabel` shown on screen is still the same as what I have initialized in Storyboard. It seems the modification doesn't work. If I refresh my `UITableView` the height of contentText will become to correct, how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not used heightForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @Bhargavi In my understanding, this function is used to change the height of cell, but my question is to change the height of uilabel

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method. This is the method usually used for UI customizations. Hope this helps!

Comment: just tried set the frame of contentText in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath, and then retrieve the contentText uilabel in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and log the frame is correct, but still wrong position displayed on screen, am I missing something?

Comment: True, this does not help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify any of the cell's frames, then you should create a subclass of UITableViewCell and implement the layoutSubviews method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  // modify frames here
}
```

Comment: if the size is changed during run time, how can I pass it to layoutSubviews? Or is there any way I can notify layoutSubviews the actual value?

Comment: tried with fixed frame, seems not working at startup, the frame will change to what I expect after view refresh

Answer (score 0):

I know its frustrating, but I also did not find a solution for that.
Instead I found myself a workaround for getting things done as I would expect them to work.

I **removed the "AutoLayout"** (Checkbox in the Storyboard)

Then:

```
[self.label setText:@"Labeltext"];
[self.label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];// just to make the frame visible
[self.label setNumberOfLines:0];
[self.label sizeToFit];
```

works like charm, but also:

```
self.label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

So, if you don't need AutoLayout (for me it's the first thing I uncheck) get rid of it.

Comment: i am afraid i cannot adapt to different screen size if the autolayout is unchecked